# Store reference to UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage

I'm sort of new with Swift programming but is it possible to store a reference to a `UIImage` instead of the `UIImage` itself.  Thinking some kind of image identifier that is a string that I can later call when I need the `UIImage` itself.

I want to be able to store an array of `[PhotoAlbum]`.   I was going to encode the array but I am not able to because `UIImage` is not encodable.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct PhotoAlbum {

    var title: String
    var thumbnail: UIImage?

    init(title: String, thumbnail: UIImage?) {
        self.title = title
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write the image to the documents folder and store its file path.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I'm using https://github.com/AYastrebov/PhotosHelper which get UIImages from an album.

Comment: @clawesome Hmm that might work.  Since the images are on my phone already thought there would be a way to just reference that one.

Comment: You should be able to get the image from photo library as a `PHAsset` which has a `localIdentifier` which should be a persistent identifier to reference a photo.

Comment: @clawesome Thanks.  I think that will work. I'm using https://github.com/AYastrebov/PhotosHelper which returns UIImages in closure. I'll look into creating a function of getting PHAssets unless you have a good resource for this handy?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a PHAsset and storing the localIdentifier.

```
var new_images: Array<Any> = []
for photo in photos {
  new_images.append(photo.localIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: `Array<Any>` is a really bad idea.